# Add/fix punctuation in php

Tags: php, punctuation

I am slowly refining a punctuation fixing function in PHP which is used to clean user input. The function currently adds spaces after punctuation, removes spaces before punctuation, and capitalizes the first word of each sentence. I have seen a few people looking for a similar function so I am happy to share what I have so far. It is pretty close to where I want it, however, when it adds a space after a comma it should avoid doing so when the comma is inside a number such as 1,000 Can anyone suggest the quickest way to modify my code to ignore commas inside numbers? Maybe there are ways to shorten what I have but still reach the same result? Thanks for your time...

```
function format_punc($string){
    $punctuation = ',.;:';
    $string = str_replace(' ?', '?', str_replace(' .', '.', str_replace(' ,', ',', preg_replace('/(['.$punctuation.'])[\s]*/', '\1 ', $string))));
    $string = trim(preg_replace('/[[:space:]]+/', ' ', preg_replace('/([\.!\?]\s+|\A)(\w)/e', '"$1" . strtoupper("$2")', $string)));
    if($string[strlen($string)-1]==','){
        $string = substr($string, 0, -1).'.';
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: How can you be sure that the comma is a thousands separator or if you're dealing with an enumeration of numbers?

Comment: That is why I posted this... I am hoping someone can help advance the function to tell if its dealing with numbers.

Comment: Some countries use different delineators for 1000s, maybe that could be divined from settings ... (just sayin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is my updated php fix punctuation function... It seems to be working correctly now. I am sure there are ways to condense it but it works to do the following to a string...

Reduce duplicate punctuation such as !! to !

Reduce multiple spaces to single spaces

Remove any spaces before ? . ,

Add spaces after ; :

Add spaces after commas but not when they are part of a number

Add spaces after periods but not when they are part of a number or abbreviation

Remove whitespace from beginning and end of string

Capitalize first word of sentences

Change last character to a period if it is a comma

```
function format_punc($string){
    $punctuation = ';:';
    $spaced_punc = array(' ?', ' .', ' ,');
    $un_spaced_punc = array('?', '.', ',');
    $string = preg_replace("/([.,!?;:])+/iS","$1",$string);
    $string = preg_replace('/[[:space:]]+/', ' ', $string);
    $string = str_replace($spaced_punc, $un_spaced_punc, $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/(['.$punctuation.'])[\s]*/', '\1 ', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/(?<!\d),|,(?!\d{3})/', ', ', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('/(\.)([[:alpha:]]{2,})/', '$1 $2', $string);
    $string = trim($string);
    $string = preg_replace('/([\.!\?]\s+|\A)(\w)/e', '"$1" . strtoupper("$2")', $string);
    if($string[strlen($string)-1]==','){
        $string = substr($string, 0, -1).'.';
    }
    return $string;
}
```

If you take the time to condense this code and create something that still returns the same results, please share! Thank you and enjoy!

Comment: how do you protect punctuation in email adresses or urls ?

Comment: For my use, content with email addresses or urls is denied before the string is passed to this function. I originally wrote this to format the string after it passes some anti-spam checks. If you modify it to properly allow+format emails or urls to meet your requirements, please do share your enhanced code here for anyone that might also be interested. Thanks. (y)

Comment: I am using a different solution. I am stripping the urls and emails before applying the cleanup, and injecting them back in at the end. Not sure where I'd put that in this thread tho.

Comment: As of PHP 7 the /e modifier is no longer supported

Comment: PHP >= 7.0 solution for /e modifier: `$string = preg_replace_callback('/([\.!\?]\s+|\A)(\w)/', function ($matches) { return strtoupper($matches[0]); }, $string);`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the regexp should be *([^0-9][.][^0-9])[\s]**

```
preg_replace('/([^0-9]['.$punctuation.'][^0-9])[\s]*/', '\1 ', $string)
```

[Link to regexp test](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%5B%5E0-9%5D%5B%5C.%5D%5B%5E0-9%5D%29%5B%5Cs%5D%2a&input=asdklfm%20asdlkfmasd%20.%20dsfsf%20dsf%20.df%20df%20df%20.%20df%20%20df%20dffff.fffdf%20df%20d%202323.234434%20-2323.343%0A%0A44%20sdsd.d%20sd%20sd%20%20.%20dsdsd%20sd.%20s%20dsdsdsd.d.dsd.s%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20sdsd.sdd%20dsf%20%0A%0A%0Asdsf%202323.%20sad%20sad%202323.3233%20asa.as)

Comment: Thanks that is close... but it causes a space such as... "String,w ord. 2,000"

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complex but it should get you in the right direction:

```
<?php

// The following finds all commas in $string and identifies which comma is preceded and followed by a number

$string = 'Hello, my name, is John,Doe. I have 3,425 cats.';

function strpos_r($haystack, $needle)
{
    if(strlen($needle) > strlen($haystack))
        trigger_error(sprintf("%s: length of argument 2 must be <= argument 1", __FUNCTION__), E_USER_WARNING);

    $seeks = array();
    while($seek = strrpos($haystack, $needle))
    {
        array_push($seeks, $seek);
        $haystack = substr($haystack, 0, $seek);
    }
    return $seeks;
}

var_dump($commas = strpos_r($string, ',')); // gives you the location of all commas

for ($i = 0; i <= count($commas) - 1; $i++)
{
    if (is_numeric($commas[$i] - 1) && is_numeric($commas[$i] + 1)) 
    {
      // this means the characters before and after a given comma are numeric
      // don't add space (or delete the space) here

    }
}
```